# Infinite loop when using regex_search with std::string

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, boost, boost-regex

Why does the following code result in an infinite loop?

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  const std::string formula = "LAST_BID_EURUSD$ LAST_ASK_USDJPY$";

  boost::smatch matches;
  boost::regex expr("(LAST_(?:BID|ASK)_.+?\\$)");
  while (boost::regex_search(formula, matches, expr))
  {
    std::cout << std::string(matches[1].first, matches[1].second) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

If I pass iterators to `begin` and `end` of `formula` instead of the `formula` itself and update the `start` one accordingly, all works as expected:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  const std::string formula = "LAST_BID_EURUSD$ LAST_ASK_USDJPY$";

  auto start = formula.begin();
  auto end = formula.end();

  boost::smatch matches;
  boost::regex expr("(LAST_(?:BID|ASK)_.+?\\$)");
  while (boost::regex_search(start, end, matches, expr))
  {
    std::cout << std::string(matches[1].first, matches[1].second) << std::endl;
    start = matches[0].second;
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
LAST_BID_EURUSD$
LAST_ASK_USDJPY$
```

The same goes for C++11 regex.

How is it supposed to be used with `std::string` objects?

Comment: `regex_search(string, matches, regex)` is just `regex_search(string.begin(), string.end(), matches, regex)`. It doesn't somehow remember the state. Use `regex_iterator` to iterator over all matches in a sequence.

Comment: In fact, you just call `regex_search` unlimited number of times.

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://ideone.com/NN6nCR) of the `std::regex` iterator.

Answer (score 3):

In the first snippet, you're making the same call over and over again.

```
boost::regex_search(formula, matches, expr)
```

It's really not surprising that this call gives the same results (i.e, succeeds) each time you call it.

In the second snippet, you are updating the `start` iterator each time through the loop, so the "string" that you're searching keeps getting smaller, until, eventually, the search fails, and the loop terminates.

```
boost::regex_search(start, end, matches, expr)
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Requires:** Type BidirectionalIterator meets the requirements of a Bidirectional Iterator (24.1.4).

This is the line written in `boost` documentation page. You need to provide `Iterators` not the object itself.

[**Boost Documentation**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html)

In c++11 documentation

> **Parameters**
>
> first, last   -   a range identifying the target character sequence

Means it needs `iterators` to define the range.

[**C++11 Documentation Page**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search)

**For your convenience, here is snippet given in the documentation page**

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

// purpose: 
// takes the contents of a file in the form of a string 
// and searches for all the C++ class definitions, storing 
// their locations in a map of strings/int's 
typedef std::map<std::string, int, std::less<std::string> > map_type;

boost::regex expression(
   "^(template[[:space:]]*<[^;:{]+>[[:space:]]*)?"
   "(class|struct)[[:space:]]*"
   "(\\<\\w+\\>([[:blank:]]*\\([^)]*\\))?"
   "[[:space:]]*)*(\\<\\w*\\>)[[:space:]]*"
   "(<[^;:{]+>[[:space:]]*)?(\\{|:[^;\\{()]*\\{)");

void IndexClasses(map_type& m, const std::string& file)
{
   std::string::const_iterator start, end;
   start = file.begin();
   end = file.end();
      boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
   boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
   while(regex_search(start, end, what, expression, flags))
   {
      // what[0] contains the whole string 
      // what[5] contains the class name. 
      // what[6] contains the template specialisation if any. 
      // add class name and position to map: 
      m[std::string(what[5].first, what[5].second)
            + std::string(what[6].first, what[6].second)]
         = what[5].first - file.begin();
      // update search position: 
      start = what[0].second;
      // update flags: 
      flags |= boost::match_prev_avail;
      flags |= boost::match_not_bob;
   }
}
```

Look at 2nd and 3rd line of the `IndexClasses` function

Because you are not providing any `Iterators`, I think, you are running into some kind of infinite loop.